# Hide div and show div at the same time?

Tags: jquery

Im learning jquery and working on a simple example that
I want to show the div when i click on a 'next' , which hides 
the last div.
It does hide the last div but not show the new one.

How would I be able to accomplish this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
  $("#hidediv").hide();
 $("#showingdiv").show();
  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="hidediv">This is a paragraph.</div>

<button class="btn1">next</button>

<div id="showingdiv><p>showing div next</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I got this information from
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_show.asp
but have change some stuff.

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HmERp/ and you have a **typo** in your `id` `:))` also ~> http://www.w3fools.com/ and if you want to read more checkout jquery.com and learn;

Comment: You're missing the closing `"` after `id="showingdiv`, so there's one long non-matching `id` (and no content) in the `div`.

Comment: thanks i do have to make more changes since i would like it to show only when i click on the hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you've got an typo in your `showingdiv` id ( it's missing the closing double quote's). Therefore, JQuery can't find the div...

Second, there's nothing to show, because it's not hidden in the first place. So i've added some CSS that will hide the second div first...

[Here's an working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uZua/)

the HTML:

```
<div id="hidediv">This is a paragraph.</div>
<button class="btn1">next</button>
<div id="showingdiv"><p>showing div next</p></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn1").click(function () {
        $("#hidediv").hide();
        $("#showingdiv").show();
    });

});
```

And CSS:

```
#showingdiv{
    display:none;
}
```

Also, You can use the JQuery function `toggle`.

It will change the display to hidden or display ( simplified... ) based on it's state.

So like an light switch, it will turn the element on ( display it ), or turn an element off ( hide it )

[Here's an working JSFiddle with the toggle function](http://jsfiddle.net/3uZua/1/)

The JS code will looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn1").click(function () {
        $("#hidediv").toggle();
        $("#showingdiv").toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: @user3591637, i'm glad this has helped you.

Comment: @user3591637, check my update regarding the JQuery function `toggle`

Comment: No, it 'toggles' the divs. So like the light switch... When you press the button, `on become off, but if it wass off, it become on`... [Here's the JQuery site api](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)